# A problem occurred evaluating project ':@react-native-community_async-storage'

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native async-storage community version which is working smoothly with iOS but not with android.

After using react-native run-android I am getting following error

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file '/Users/blickx/Desktop/dumont-reactnative/Dumont/node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage/android/build.gradle'
>     line: 36
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':@react-native-community_async-storage'.
>
>   > Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 5s
>
> ```
> at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
> at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
> at runOnAllDevices (/Users/blickx/Desktop/dumont-reactnative/Dumont/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
> at buildAndRun (/Users/blickx/Desktop/dumont-reactnative/Dumont/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:158:41)
> at /Users/blickx/Desktop/dumont-reactnative/Dumont/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:125:12
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
> at async Command.handleAction (/Users/blickx/Desktop/dumont-reactnative/Dumont/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/cliEntry.js:160:7)
> ```

Comment: which version of RN are you using?  and have you linked it manually?

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.61.1

Comment: nope. I have linked it using the link command. However, I have manual linking also. both are same.

Comment: one thing ,  is your app not working? like for me too after react-native run-android it says build failed but i can use my app in my phone after connecting it via wifi. have you tried that?

Comment: When I run command react-native run-android it throw the error. It doesn't matter from which network you are connected.

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess you should clean your build by navigating to android directory(cd android) then run ./gradlew clean . Then go to your project directory (cd ..) then run react-native run-android

Comment: One thing more that there is automatic linking fron react-natice 0.60 ver, so no need of linking it manually

Comment: when i am doing cd to android and running the clean command it throws the error saying: 
When i am doing this i got this error could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: However, I am linking it manually.

Comment: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 57

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

It seems you have a missing android plugin which is causing the issue for you.

### Solution

Instruct Gradle to download Android plugin from Maven Central repository.
You do it by pasting the following code at the beginning of the Gradle build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    }
}
```

**Note:** Make sure your project is using Gradle 3.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: When i am doing this i got this error could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 57

Answer (score -1):

In settings.gradle file find this

include ':@react-native-async-storage_async-storage'
project(':@react-native-async-storage_async-storage').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android')

copy the ':@react-native-async-storage_async-storage' in the include line and paste the same to implementation project line in build.gradle

Like this ->

dependencies {

......

implementation project(':@react-native-async-storage_async-storage') //<- paste this

.....
}