# A problem occurred configuring project ':@react-native-async-storage_async-storage'

Tags: android, react-native, asyncstorage

I get this error when I try to run `react-native run-android`.

This is the full error message:

> A problem occurred configuring project ':@react-native-async-storage_async-storage'.
> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: defaultConfig contains custom BuildConfig fields, but the feature is disabled.
> To enable the feature, add the following to your module-level build.gradle:
> `android.buildFeatures.buildConfig true`

I've found these solutions to similar errors: [this](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage/issues/188), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58520430/a-problem-occurred-evaluating-project-react-native-community-async-storage), [this](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage/issues/405) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72719834/react-native-v0-68-a-problem-occurred-configuring-project-react-native-async) but, the problem still remains.

In other words,

1. I updated my java version to 15 (I tried also 19).
2. I tried different Gradle Versions (mainly of 8+).
3. I installed `npm i jetifier`.
4. I added `android.buildFeatures.buildConfig true` in `android/app/build.gradle` (ChatGPT suggestion).
5. There is also a suggestion to the issue I've opened [here](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage/issues/908)
6. I updated Android Studio

Additional notes:

- The app is uploaded in Play Store and the last time I worked on it, was three months ago. So I guess I have to update something.
- I used to have the community package `@react-native-community/async-storage`, which is deprecated, so I replaced it with this one: `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage`.

Comment: There might be some tips to resolve this in the thread over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74634321/fixing-the-build-type-contains-custom-buildconfig-fields-but-the-feature-is-di